# Cant get variables via _post IF form Has a name, like form3

Tags: php, forms, variables

i discovered, if a form has aname  in html, i cannot get variables via $_post .
Example;

```
<form action="" name="form1"  method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="1">
</form>

<form action="" name="form1"  method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="text" name="e_mail" />
</form>

<?php 
$e_mail= $_POST['e_mail'];
 echo "$e_mail";
?>
```

no matter what i did , didint work.
in the end i deleted that "name=form1" and joined the 's together .. like this;;

```
<form action=""  method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8"> //deleted name=form1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="1">

<input type="text" name="e_mail" />
</form>
```

magically WORKED!! (happy)..  dont know why? but it worked..

i just wanted to help if anyone comes across with this NON-ERROR_giving annoyance.

and this is happening When i use dreamWeaver to create table.  what a devil dreamWeaver are you.. you really eat all my youth.

Comment: name=form1 should have had  quotes around "form1"

Comment: Are you sure, you submitted the right form? A POST-request only contains the data from the form you submitted.

Comment: i added that manually to show every "victim of weird php"  not to get insane and lose 3 hour on this NON-ERROR_giving annoyance.

Comment: Its not a non-error giving annoyance, your markup was wrong. See answers provided.

Comment: ooo i havent realized that till now . didnt even think that would be.
i thougt it would be like if you submit than all pages boom goes.. thanks .. """jreuab""

Comment: viking as i already told you thats not the issue name=form1  is wrong posted here but in my code its right and like this "form1"  as you said .. thank you too. i made mistake

Comment: @user3251369 Was that sarcasm? Also, it is not PHP error at all. PHP doesn't know about your weird markup.

Comment: no no.. i dont know anyting abut php . when submit is happening i assume al the time all page variable goes with post . no sarcasm. REALLY Thank you

i was thinking about $var =$ _Post[form1.e_mail]; 
i am non native . if i offended you anyway im contently sorry. 
im sorry from my heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="" name="form1"  method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="1">
<input type="text" name="e_mail" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['e_mail'])){
 echo "$e_mail";
}
?>
```

php will throw an error the way you have it. Also, you would only need 2 forms if you are going to have them process differently.